# Flex chart not displaying right values along x axis

Tags: apache-flex, charts, bar-chart, linechart

I don't know of any better way to ask this question.

If the below code is run 
(i know the cData sections are not visible in the preview, something causes it to be ignored).

The result does not represent the data correctly.
1. Flex ignores missing date 24 aug for DECKER.
2. It wrongly associates 42.77 to 23-Aug instead of 24-AUG.

Is there a way in flex,
where the x-axis is a union of all available points ?

The below code is entirely from :
[Adobe website link](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_types_12.html)

I have only commented 2 data points.
//{date:"23-Aug-05", close:45.74},
and 
//{date:"24-Aug-05", close:150.71},

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
 [Bindable]
  public var SMITH:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
    {date:"22-Aug-05", close:41.87},
    //{date:"23-Aug-05", close:45.74},
    {date:"24-Aug-05", close:42.77},
    {date:"25-Aug-05", close:48.06},
 ]);

 [Bindable]
  public var DECKER:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
    {date:"22-Aug-05", close:157.59},
    {date:"23-Aug-05", close:160.3},
    //{date:"24-Aug-05", close:150.71},
    {date:"25-Aug-05", close:156.88},
 ]);

[Bindable]
public var deckerColor:Number = 0x224488;

[Bindable]
public var smithColor:Number = 0x884422;
```

]]>

```
    <mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>
        <mx:AxisRenderer placement="bottom" axis="{h1}"/>
    </mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>

    <mx:verticalAxisRenderers>
        <mx:AxisRenderer placement="left" axis="{v1}">
            <mx:axisStroke>{h1Stroke}</mx:axisStroke>
        </mx:AxisRenderer>
        <mx:AxisRenderer placement="left" axis="{v2}">
            <mx:axisStroke>{h2Stroke}</mx:axisStroke>
        </mx:AxisRenderer>
    </mx:verticalAxisRenderers>

    <mx:series>
       <mx:ColumnSeries id="cs1" 
            horizontalAxis="{h1}" 
            dataProvider="{SMITH}" 
            yField="close" 
            displayName="SMITH"
        >
            <mx:fill>
                <mx:SolidColor color="{smithColor}"/>
            </mx:fill>

            <mx:verticalAxis>
               <mx:LinearAxis id="v1" minimum="40" maximum="50"/>
            </mx:verticalAxis>           
       </mx:ColumnSeries>           
       <mx:LineSeries id="cs2" 
            horizontalAxis="{h1}" 
            dataProvider="{DECKER}" 
            yField="close" 
            displayName="DECKER"
        >
            <mx:verticalAxis>
                <mx:LinearAxis id="v2" minimum="150" maximum="170"/>           
            </mx:verticalAxis>

            <mx:lineStroke>
                <mx:Stroke 
                    color="{deckerColor}" 
                    weight="4" 
                    alpha="1"
                />
            </mx:lineStroke>
       </mx:LineSeries>
    </mx:series>
 </mx:ColumnChart>
 <mx:Legend dataProvider="{myChart}"/>
```

Comment: Looks like in a multi-graph scenario, flex ignores the values in the collection and goes by the indexs in the array Collection.
To test this: I reordered the dates as ( 24 , 25, 22, 23 ) for smith and (22 , 23 , 24, 25) for decker. 

The result is : the Smiths value for 24th was associated with decker's value for the 22.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching ,

The above source used 2 different datasources and 2 different series.
Each of datasource is associated with one series. So, there is a 1:1 between datasource : series.

However,

The accepted way to seams to be to use one data source and 2 series.
The datasource has one field associated with each of the series. So , there is a 1:1 between dataField : series.

I resolved the problem using the second approach, but that means we have to manually construct a single datasource with right values.

Answer (score 0):

If you switch to /* */style quotes instead of // does it fix the problem? I think the compiler thinks your array collection is all one line (regardless of line breaks) so you may not be able to use // style quotes in it.

Comment: Ok, I removed the entire data point itself (deleted), 
So, I have 22-Aug, 24-Aug, 25- Aug for SMITH, 
Yet the chart associates 42.77 with 23-Aug .

Comment: Are you overrwriting the array collections anywhere? I don't see how Aug-23 could get into the SMITH array collection otherwise.

Comment: no, there are 2 graphs, one for smith, one for decker.
decker is initialized after smith. so, flex is taking the coordinates of decker for x-axis and assigning y values from smith.
if you see smith, it has three dates, 22 - 24 - 25. while decker has 22- 23 - 25. flex gives an x axis with 22- 23 - 25 instead of union of the two =( 22- 23- 24- 25).